# Rails action caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a rails based api project, and I'm thinking about caching at this point. I'm using `rails-api` gem along with some rails goodies.

And I was reading this README :

https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching

And tried some things with memchached cache([dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli)). So consider this action, it's a PUT request :

- Cache read: http://localhost/users/310

So the action is cached every next time I try to update. It's not going in my update method, why is this? And is this a good strategy? I mean there is `caches_action` where you can cache only certain actions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should cache things that return the same data when they're requested, and you should never cache things that are modifying data. What this normally means is that GET requests are the only candidates for caching. Caching your update method will prevent your update method from updating.